# JavaScript Regex for numbers and spaces surrounded by specific strings

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to find two values which are in the following format where I have two numbers of indeterminate length separated by a space.

```
<div name='something'>123 456</div><other HTML...> </other HTML>
```

Using the unique `name='something'` I want to know what the first number and second numbers are.

I am doing the following

```
var xhack = arraytrans.match("<div name='something'>(.*)</div>");
var values = xhack[1];
var z_value = values.split(' ')[0];
var x_value = values.split(' ')[1];
```

However this results in scenarios where the x value ends up being a bunch of trailing HTML from `<other HTML>`.

Any ideas what the right regex is to get x and z values here?

Comment: Why do you have `"` after `<`?

Comment: Are double quote markers extra?

Comment: [Matching html with a reg exp is a bad idea.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not)

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/pQ9wP7/1 something like this?

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML has `name=something`, but your regexp is looking for `name='something'` (with quotes around `something`). You need to change it to:

```
var xhack = arraytrans.match("<div name=something>([^<]*)</div>");
```

I've also changed `.*` to `[^<]*` so that it won't match across multiple DIVs.